# Swift: Setting Delegates

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I think I have a misunderstanding with delegates in swift. What I m trying to do is, to add a textField into my Controller programmatically. Therefore, I edited my class as seen below:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextFieldDelegate {
}
```

In my understanding, now I can add a UITextFieldDelegate to my Textfield and it will call the extention.
But somehow everytime I set the delegate it tells me that:

> Cannot assign value of type '(HomeController) -> () -> HomeController' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'

Therefore, I wanted to know, how I can set the delegate of my TextField to the UITextFieldDelegate?

My class looks as follows:

```
 class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextFieldDelegate {
  let sampleTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    textField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    textField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
    textField.delegate = self

    return textField
 }()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
let sampleTextField: UITextField = {
```

to:

```
lazy var sampleTextField: UITextField = {
```

---

**Edit**

To add some clarification...

When declaring a property (class-level variable) with `var` or `let`, it is instantiated immediately, and doesn't know anything about the rest of the class.

If you use `lazy var`, it is not instantiated until it is ***first used***... at which point it *does* know about the class and it has access to `self`.

Comment: Wow ... That worked :D. Thank you very much ! Could you maybe explain a little bit why I need to do that or share a link were I can read a little more :)

Comment: @Benipro98 - I added a little clarification to my answer.